# How to call functions in other class without type class at first time?

Tags: dart, flutter

for example, I have a class named Fn, in Fn I have function named myFunc, so I use and call the function is like this

```
import 'fn.dart';

Fn().myFunc();
```

I want just type

```
myFunc();
```

How I can do that? thank you so much for your help.

Comment: As Doc says, just implement `myFunc` *outside* of a class - it becomes a top level function.

Comment: yes if your function `myFunc()` is not related to class and can work independently then make it a top-level function and call it directly. Other options are explained in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you say `Fn().myFunc();` you are creating an instance of `Fn` which creates useless objects every time.

What you should do is

`Fn fn = Fn();`
and then
`fn.myFunc();` everytime you want to call the function

Further, if you want then you can create static methods like

```
class A {
  static void bar() {} // A static method
  void baz() {} // An instance method
}
```

then we have

`A.bar();` for static method

or

`A a = A();` and `a.baz();` everytime you need to call `baz`, which is an instance method.

Note: you can have top-level function outside of class also in dart. Read https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour